# PHP 5 soapClient result is empty __getLastResponse shows correct XML

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

When using a Soap Service the result is empty why the XML is populated in getLastResponse. Here is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Search" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:s1="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Common" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Search" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">A web service used to perform searches on an instance's data.</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Search">
      <s:import namespace="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Common" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8090/Services/Common.xsd" />
      <s:element name="SearchRequest" type="tns:SearchRequest" />
      <s:complexType name="SearchRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Contexts" type="s1:FilterContext" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="SearchResponse" type="tns:SearchResponse" />
      <s:complexType name="SearchResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Items" type="tns:SearchResultItem" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status" type="s1:SoapResponseStatus" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="SearchResultItem">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="s1:ItemKey">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DisplayName" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ResultType" type="s1:FilterContextType" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="SearchSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="Request" element="tns:SearchRequest" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="SearchSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="SearchResult" element="tns:SearchResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SearchWebServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Search">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Performs a search based on requested contexts and filters.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:SearchSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:SearchSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="SearchWebServiceSoap" type="tns:SearchWebServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Search">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Search/Search" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="SearchWebServiceSoap12" type="tns:SearchWebServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Search">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Search/Search" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SearchWebService">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">A web service used to perform searches on an instance's data.</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port name="SearchWebServiceSoap" binding="tns:SearchWebServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:50295/Services/SearchWebService.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="SearchWebServiceSoap12" binding="tns:SearchWebServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:50295/Services/SearchWebService.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:schema xmlns="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Common"
          xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          elementFormDefault="qualified"
          targetNamespace="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Common">
  <s:complexType name="ItemKey">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SiteId" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemId" type="s:int" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="SoapResponseStatus">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Succeeded" type="s:boolean" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ErrorCode" type="s:int" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="ItemKeyRequest">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="ItemKey" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="FilterContext">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="IFilter">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ContextType" type="FilterContextType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FilterGroup" type="FilterGroup" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="IFilter" abstract="true" />
  <s:complexType name="FilterValue">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="IFilter">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OperatorType" type="OperatorType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SchemaTypeName" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SchemaTypeNamespace" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:simpleType name="OperatorType">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="NotSet" />
      <s:enumeration value="Equal" />
      <s:enumeration value="GreaterThan" />
      <s:enumeration value="LessThan" />
      <s:enumeration value="GreaterThanEqual" />
      <s:enumeration value="LessThanEqual" />
      <s:enumeration value="Contains" />
      <s:enumeration value="StartsWith" />
      <s:enumeration value="EndsWith" />
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
  <s:complexType name="FilterContainer">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="IFilter">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FilterValue" type="FilterValue" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FilterGroup" type="FilterGroup" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="FilterGroup">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="IFilter">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GroupType" type="FilterGroupType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Filters" type="FilterContainer" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:simpleType name="FilterGroupType">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="And" />
      <s:enumeration value="Or" />
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
  <s:simpleType name="FilterContextType">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="Hierarchy" />
      <s:enumeration value="ReportDefinition" />
      <s:enumeration value="GeneratedReport" />
      <s:enumeration value="Role" />
      <s:enumeration value="User" />
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
</s:schema>
```

PHP Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("SearchWebService.wsdl", array('location' => "$usingSSL://$hostname/axis2/services/SearchWebService", 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["data"]));
$result = $client->Search($data);
```

__getLastResponse:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <n:SearchResponse xmlns:n="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Search" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n0="http://schema.XXX.com/WebAPI/1.0/Common">
            <n:Responses>
                <n:Items>
                    <n0:SiteId/>
                    <n0:ItemId>22</n0:ItemId>
                    <n:DisplayName>Floor 1</n:DisplayName>
                    <n:ResultType>Hierarchy</n:ResultType>
                </n:Items>
                <n:Items>
                    <n0:SiteId/>
                    <n0:ItemId>196</n0:ItemId>
                    <n:DisplayName>Floor 1</n:DisplayName>
                    <n:ResultType>Hierarchy</n:ResultType>
                </n:Items>
                <n:Status>
                    <n0:Succeeded>true</n0:Succeeded>
                    <n0:ErrorCode>0</n0:ErrorCode>
                </n:Status>
            </n:Responses>
        </n:SearchResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

$result is always empty. No errors. I tried classmaps and same result.

Any idea's?

Comment: What happens if you take the `'location'=>'...'` and move it to the first parameter in the SoapClient instantiation? Like so: `$client = new SoapClient("$usingSSL://$hostname/axis2/services/SearchWebService", array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));`

Comment: @Psychoboy - I am running into a very similar issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Buggabill What I actually had to do was change the wsdl (service) and remove the extends

Answer (score 0):

try a var_dump() on results... what do you see?

Also, you could try this too, wrap this around the Search call:

```
try {
  $result = $client->Search($data);
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
  //We errored 
  echo $exception;
}
```